# The row-limitation in compound primary key in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I am going to insert a 2.3 billion rows (2,300,000,000) from `table_a` into `table_b`. The schema of `table_a` and `table_b` are identical, the only difference is `table_a` doesn't have a primary key but `table_b` has set up a 4 columns compound primary key with 0 rows of data. I encounter the error message after 24 hours:

> Msg 666, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
>   The maximum system-generated unique value for a duplicate group was exceeded for index with partition ID 422223771074560. Dropping and re-creating the index may resolve this; otherwise, use another clustering key.

This is my compound PK in `table_b` and the sample query code, any help will be thankful.

```
column1: varchar(10), not null
column2: nvarchar(50), not null
column3: nvarchar(100), not null
column4: int, not null
```

Sample code

```
insert into table_b
    select * 
    from table_a
    where date < '2017-01-01' -- some filters here
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [SQL Server Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-index-design-guide?view=sql-server-2017&viewFallbackFrom=sql-server-2014) part of creating a primary key includes creating a unique index on that same table.

> When you create a PRIMARY KEY constraint, a unique index on the
>   column, or columns, is automatically created. By default, this index
>   is clustered; however, you can specify a nonclustered index when you
>   create the constraint.

When a unique index is **not** on the table, each row gets what the docs are calling a "uniqueifier" which is 4 bytes in length (aka ~2.14 Billion combinations)

> If the clustered index is not created with the UNIQUE property, the
>   Database Engine automatically adds a 4-byte uniqueifier column to the
>   table. When it is required, the Database Engine automatically adds a
>   uniqueifier value to a row to make each key unique. This column and
>   its values are used internally and cannot be seen or accessed by
>   users.

From this information and your error message we can tell two things:

1. There is a clustered index on the table
2. There is not a primary key on the table

Given the volume of the data you're dealing with, I'm betting you have a [Clustered Columnstore Index](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/columnstore-indexes-described?view=sql-server-2014) on the table, which in SQL Server 2014 does not have the ability to have a primary key on.

One possible solution is to partition `table_b` based on particular column value (that has less than 15K unique values based on the limitations specified in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/partitions/create-partitioned-tables-and-indexes?view=sql-server-2014)). As a side-note, the same partitioning effort could have a significant impact on minimizing run time of any queries using `table_b` depending on which column is used in the partition function.

Answer (score 0):

You know that:

> If the clustered index is not created with the UNIQUE property, the
>   Database Engine automatically adds a 4-byte uniqueifier column to the
>   table. When it is required, the Database Engine automatically adds a
>   uniqueifier value to a row to make each key unique. This column and
>   its values are used internally and cannot be seen or accessed by
>   users.

While it´s unlikely that you will face an issue related with uniqueifiers, we have seen rare cases where customer reaches the uniqueifier limit of 2,147,483,648, generating error 666.

And from this [topic](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/psssql/2018/02/16/uniqueifier-considerations-and-error-666/) about the issue we have:

> As of February 2018, the design goal for the storage engine is to not
>   reset uniqueifiers during REBUILDs. As such, rebuild of the index
>   ideally would not reset uniquifiers and issue would continue to occur,
>   while inserting new data with a key value for which the uniquifiers
>   were exhausted. But current engine behavior is different for one
>   specific case, if you use the statement ALTER INDEX ALL ON 
>   REBUILD WITH (ONLINE = ON), it will reset the uniqueifiers (across all
>   version starting SQL Server 2005 to SQL Server 2017).

So, if this is the cause if your issue, you can add additional integer column and build the index over it.